# Axios typescript cannot read properties of undefined ("reading 'post')

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement an axios request inside an express app to query an external API. I looks fine but when I call the function I see a TypeError : `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')`.

This is my code:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as express from "express";
import * as cors from "cors";
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";
import * as querystring from "querystring";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();
const auth = admin.auth();
const db = admin.firestore();
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.post("/loginWithCode", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("welcome to loginWithCode");
  // Check for error or code
  const { code, devMode } = req.body;

  const redirectUri = devMode
    ? process.env.DEV_SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URL
    : process.env.SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URL;
  console.log("lets call a try block");
  try {
    // Retrieve access and refresh tokens
    const urlEncodedData = {
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: redirectUri,
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
    };

    const tokenExchangeResult = await axios.post(
      "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
      querystring.stringify(urlEncodedData),
      {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          Authorization:
            "Basic " +
            new Buffer(
              process.env.CLIENT_ID + ":" + process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
            ).toString("base64"),
        },
      }
    );
    const { accessToken, refreshToken, expiresIn } = tokenExchangeResult.data;
```

When the TS gets compiled, the line in question is compiled to read:

```
        const tokenExchangeResult = await axios_1.default.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", querystring.stringify(urlEncodedData), {
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                Authorization: "Basic " +
                    new Buffer(process.env.CLIENT_ID + ":" + process.env.CLIENT_SECRET).toString("base64"),
            },
        });
```

I can see that axios_1 is created as `const axios_1 = require("axios");`

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening

Comment: What version of axios do you use?

Comment: I guess this has changed but there was at some point no `default` export for axios, https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/530 (i.e. `axios_1.default.` won't work unless you enable those synthetic default exports) And apparently there have been changes again recently: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5038#issuecomment-1270982590

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I just ran `npm i axios`, so the package.json is saying 1.1.2

Comment: @zapl thanks for the reply, I suspect that might be part of the issue they keep saying it's fixed though. Perhaps I'll try fixing to an older version for now

Comment: Thanks @Phil I see that is almost the same as Zapl's reply so I will try an older version to see

Comment: I've downgraded now all the way to 0.27.0 and axios is now working in my Firebase Functions Typescript code

Comment: `const axios = require('axios'); ` use this to import axios